# SQL Server : Credential Account Best Practice

Tags: sql-server, powershell, jobs, agent

I have a SQL Server Agent job that runs a PowerShell script. I tried using the PowerShell job type but I found it failed silently no matter what I did.

Then I found an article about how to use the operating system job type to run PowerShell scripts and get them to fail properly.

It works great. Except I had to create a credential and use that with a proxy and use the proxy to run the job steps.

The only issue is that this job needs to run every night for the foreseeable future and at the minute the credential is using my admin account. The main prob with that is my admin account password will change and then the credential will be wrong and the job will fail.

So in a long winded way the question is: what kind of account can I use long term for this?

It's a best practice question so I'm really looking to find out how others are doing it.

Comment: Why does it need admin rights, can it not run under SQL Server Agent's login instead?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for getting back to me. It needs to access a network share and another instance of sql

Comment: You could create a special service account. Give it a very long random password which never changes